# Simple jQuery variable issue - conflicting variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I am trying to use this great jQuery text slider here: http://codepen.io/mikedevelops/pen/eNjeJm

But I really need two sliders on the same page. I have attempted to duplicate the code and change the variable names in the second slider to prevent there being an issue - but can't seem to get it to work. Here is my attempt, with the jquery below: http://codepen.io/hardanger/pen/NqmOom

**Just to be clear,** I think it is an issue with variables.

```
// add as many adjectives as you like!
var adjs = ["very cool", "really exciting", " super awesome", "jQuery sliding"],
sentence = $('#sentence'),
adjList = $('#adjList'),
stop = false;

    // function to return the most up-to-date
    // version of our adjective list
    function getList() {
       return $('.adj');
    }

    // function to build the adjective list
    // args: adjective array
    function build(arr) {
       for (i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
          var item = "<li class='adj'>";
          $(adjList).append(item + arr[i] + "</li>");
       }
    }

    // function to resize adjective list
    // args: adjective list item
    function resize(el) {
       $(adjList).animate({
          width: $(el).width(),
       }, 200);
    }

    // function to add slide-in transition
    // args: element that needs to slide
    function slideIn(el) {
       // duration slide is on screen
       var hold = 1000;
       // resize area to sliding element
       resize($(el));
       // add slide-in class
       $(el).addClass('slide-in');  
       // after 'hold' duration slide-out current item
       // then slide in next item
       setTimeout(function(){
          // check to see if loop should continue
          if (stop === true) {
             stop = false;
             return;
          }
          // slide current element out
          slideOut(el);
          // slide in next element in queue
          slideIn($(el).next());
}, hold);
    }

    // function to add slide-out transition
    // args: element that needs to slide
    function slideOut(el) {
// remove current class and add slide-out transition
$(el).removeClass('slide-in').addClass('slide-out');
// wait for slide tramsition to finish then
// call 'change' function
setTimeout(function(){
    change();
}, 200);
    }

    // function to re-arrange adjective list
    function change() { 
// store last item index
var i = adjs.length - 1;
// detach element that has slide-out class
// put to the bottom of the list after
// the last item
$('.adj:eq(' + i + ')').after($('.slide-out').detach());
// remove class to send element back to original position
$('.adj').removeClass('slide-out');
    }

    // build slider
    build(adjs);
    // init loop
    slideIn(getList()[0]);


    // second slider


    // add as many adjectives as you like!
    var adjs2 = ["test", "test", " testtesttesttesttesttest", "test"],
sentence2 = $('#sentence2'),
adjList2 = $('#adjList2'),
stop = false;

    // function to return the most up-to-date
    // version of our adjective list
    function getList2() {
return $('.adj2');
    }

    // function to build the adjective list
    // args: adjective array
    function build(arr2) {
for (i2=0; i2<arr2.length; i2++) {
    var item2 = "<li class='adj2'>";
    $(adjList2).append(item2 + arr2[i2] + "</li>");
}
    }

    // function to resize adjective list
    // args: adjective list item
    function resize(el2) {
$(adjList2).animate({
    width: $(el2).width(),
}, 200);
    }

    // function to add slide-in transition
    // args: element that needs to slide
    function slideIn2(el2) {
// duration slide is on screen
var hold2 = 1000;
// resize area to sliding element
resize($(el2));
// add slide-in class
$(el2).addClass('slide-in2');   
// after 'hold' duration slide-out current item
// then slide in next item
setTimeout(function(){
    // check to see if loop should continue
    if (stop === true) {
        stop = false;
        return;
    }
    // slide current element out
    slideOut2(el2);
    // slide in next element in queue
    slideIn2($(el2).next());
}, hold2);
    }

    // function to add slide-out transition
    // args: element that needs to slide
    function slideOut2(el2) {
// remove current class and add slide-out transition
$(el2).removeClass('slide-in2').addClass('slide-out2');
// wait for slide tramsition to finish then
// call 'change' function
setTimeout(function(){
    change();
}, 200);
    }

    // function to re-arrange adjective list
    function change() { 
// store last item index
var i2 = adjs2.length - 1;
// detach element that has slide-out class
// put to the bottom of the list after
// the last item
$('.adj2:eq(' + i2 + ')').after($('.slide-out2').detach());
// remove class to send element back to original position
$('.adj2').removeClass('slide-out2');
    }

    // build slider
    build(adjs2);
    // init loop
    slideIn2(getList2()[0]);
```

Comment: Can you provide your html?

Comment: Rather than copy/paste/rename the code, you would be better off encapsulating it in a way that you can inject references to the UI elements it will work with.

Comment: @Abhisek Malakar Thanks for the comment - the full code can be seen in the provided links in the question.

Comment: @JackA. Hi Jack - that sounds like a good solution, but I'm afraid I can't see how that would work in actual code terms - please could you provide a few more details?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to encapslate the code. A good pattern in this case would be as a [jQuery plugin](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/). The key to proper encapsulation is to remove global references in order to isolate the code and inject whatever the code needs to operate.

Global references can be tricky because they can come in many forms. In this case, the original code you linked in your question contains references to global variables in the JavaScript (e.g., the `adjs` array) and specific DOM elements by ID and class (e.g., `$('#adjList')` and `$('.slide-out')`). You have to be careful with classes because when you select by class, you get *all* the elements on the page with that class. This is a problem for the original code because you only want a subset of the elements with that class.

The style sheet can have a problem with global references as well. In the original code, the style sheet was using IDs to style the elements, which means there could only be one of the element on the page. You really want to use classes that can be applied to multiple elements.

The most basic things that the JavaScript code really needs to know about is the DOM element in which the text will be swapped (`<ul id="adjList">`), and the list of texts to be swapped. The call to a jQuery plugin for this would look something like this:

```
$('#adjList').textSlider(adjs);
```

I made a somewhat hacked up but functional jQuery plugin from the original code here:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JdVVje

The main changes were to wrap the appropriate code as a plugin, fix the ID references in the style sheet, and fix the style references in the JavaScript code. As you can see, there are two working text sliders on the page now.